# Stringtemplate - use conditionals without adding newlines to the output, and still keep templates legible?

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I have something like this:

```
properties(attributeInfo) ::= <<
private <attributeInfo:parameters()>;

>>

parameters(attributeInfo) ::= <<
<if(attributeInfo.struct||attributeInfo.array)><attributeInfo:paramComposite()><else><javaTypeNameMap.(attributeInfo.typeName)> <attributeInfo.propertyName><endif>
>>
```

This produces the desired output:

```
private com.terradatum.common.db.model.terradatum.MlsAgentIdObj agentObj;
private String officeName;
private String officeAddress;
private String officeCity;
private String officeState;
private String officeZipcode;
private MlsPhoneTbl phoneTbl;
private String agentEmail;
private String agentAddress;
private String agentCity;
private String agentState;
private String agentZipcode;
```

When I change the `parameters` subtemplate to the following:

```
parameters(attributeInfo) ::= <<
<if(attributeInfo.struct||attributeInfo.array)><attributeInfo:paramComposite()>
<else><javaTypeNameMap.(attributeInfo.typeName)> <attributeInfo.propertyName>
<endif>
>>
```

The template is more legible, but the output now includes newlines:

```
private com.terradatum.common.db.model.terradatum.MlsAgentIdObj agentObj
;
private String officeName
;
private String officeAddress
;
private String officeCity
;
private String officeState
;
private String officeZipcode
;
private MlsPhoneTbl phoneTbl
;
private String agentEmail
;
private String agentAddress
;
private String agentCity
;
private String agentState
;
private String agentZipcode
;
```

I'm confused by this behavior - based on what I understood about how to conditionally include subtemplates, and the behavior of conditionals WRT to newlines, the two forms of the `parameters` subtemplate should produce the same output.

Clearly my understanding is incorrect, so I'm hoping someone will give me some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
parameters(attributeInfo) ::= <%
<if(attributeInfo.struct||attributeInfo.array>
  <attributeInfo:paramComposite()>
<else><javaTypeNameMap.(attributeInfo.typeName)>
  <attributeInfo.propertyName>
<endif>
%>
```

`<% ...%>` lets stringtemplate ignore separating white space. `<< ...>>` only ignores leading and trailing newlines.

In some case also the call of the function `trim` could help.

Comment: That did _most_ of the trick - it's still something of challenge, but definitely more legible.